# Underlying implementation of normalize() and length() in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, glsles

What is the underlying implementation of normalize() and length() in GLSL? I am trying to gauge the performance of my code and what to know what instructions are being executed for certain built in functions in GLSL. Where can I get more information on the underlying implementation of other built in functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OpenGL Shading Language spec generally doesn't require a particular implementation of its functions, as long as they give the results it specifies. In GLSL 4.5, for example, see the correctness requirements on page 84, and the functions `length()` and `normalize()` on page 150.

Moreover, GLSL doesn't define a binary format for compiled shader code; that format is accordingly implementation dependent.

However, in general, I presume the `length` function would be implemented using a dot product and a square root, and the `normalize` function would be implemented by calling the `length` function and also doing three divisions, or one division and a vector multiplication.

Comment: I would expect most hardware to use a built-in inverse sqrt instruction. This ought to be faster than a normal sqrt alone, let alone the benefit of doing a multiplication instead of a division.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is wildly GPU/vendor dependent ; but it may give you a clue to look at the output provided by [AMD Shader Analyser](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/gpu-shaderanalyzer/) or take a peek into 'binary' dumps of compiled shaders on NVidia - last time I checked (long time ago), they were containing assembly code in text form.